# Background usage even if the app put to sleep

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, background-process, sleep

I have put the WhatsApp to sleep (App Usage --> Put app to sleep ( ON ) ) but when I checked on the battery usage, it shows 1 h 6 min.

I'm using Android Pie on Samsung Galaxy Note 8.

How I can ensure that the app will not use battery in background. I guess one way to use the 'Force stop' in app manager.

Comment: How did you put to "sleep"?

Comment: @IrfanLatif App Usage --> Put app to sleep ( ON )

Comment: It seems to be a [Samsung specific](https://www.sammobile.com/2016/11/28/whats-new-nougat-part-11-save-battery-apps-sleep/) feature, not of AOSP. So I'm not sure what it actually does to the app, but for sure it must not be completely killing the app. Stock Android uses different phenomenon to put restrictions on apps' background activities e.g. doze and app standby. Battery saver mode aggressively forces apps to standby as well as blocks network activities.

Comment: But the best background limitations are applied with appops RIN_IN_BACKGROUND denied, in which restricted apps cannot run jobs, trigger alarms, or use the network, except when the app is in the foreground. However none of them *kills* the app. So you may see somewhat resources used by app.